# Simplifying an associative array()

Tags: php, array

Would it be better to convert the array in the following code to

```
$langs = array("en", "de", "fr");
```

and then reusing the values for both `$folder` and `$flag`? If so, how then would my foreach (or maybe a while?) loop be written?

```
<?php
    $langs = array(
        "en/" => "en.png",
        "de/" => "de.png",
        "fr/" => "fr.png"
    );
    $self    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pattern = "{^.*/}i";
    $links   = array();
    foreach ($langs as $folder => $flag) {
        $url  = preg_replace($pattern, "$folder", $self);
        $link = "<li><a href=\"../$url\"><img src=\"../img/$flag\"></a></li>";
        array_push($links, $link);
    }
    echo implode($links) . "\n";
?>
```

I'm trying to "fool proof" the code, by effectively limiting the folder structures and file names that can be used, as I create a basic template of files for quick rolling out of our websites. If you can see any other improvements, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely simplify this, as the only part of each element of `$langs` that changes is the two-letter language code. Something like this would work:

```
<?php
$langs = array(
    "en",
    "de",
    "fr"
);
$self    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pattern = "{^.*/}i";
$links   = array();
foreach ($langs as $code) {
    $url  = preg_replace($pattern, "$code/", $self);
    $link = "<li><a href=\"../$url\"><img src=\"../img/$code.png\"></a></li>";
    array_push($links, $link);
}
echo implode($links) . "\n";
?>
```

You just use a non-associative array and append `/` or `.png` where needed; much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you. Once you see it written out, you realise it's so simple yet so effective!